# Virtual function causing undefined reference error in moc-generated .o files

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Why does the following code give me an undefined reference error upon compilation?

```
#include <QObject>

class QT_PORT_WRAPPER_C : public QObject
{

  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    //constructor
    QT_PORT_WRAPPER_C(){};

  protected:
    virtual void input_port_impk( const char *data ); //causes error

};
```

The error message is:

> /home/abc/work/build-exp-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/moc_receiver.o:-1:
>   error: undefined reference to `QT_PORT_WRAPPER_C::input_port_impk(char
>   const*)'

If I change `virtual void input_port_impk( const char *data );` to either `void input_port_impk( const char *data );` or `virtual void input_port_impk( const char *data ) = 0;`, the error goes away. Why?

Comment: change to `virtual void input_port_impk( const char *data ){}`, if you are not going to implement it, you must use `= 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accessing virtual protected functions of a base class not allowed through a pointer of the base class type inside a derived class

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:

        void go(){this->doSomething();}

    protected:
        virtual void doSomething(){std::cout << "base";}
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
    protected:
        void doSomething() override {std::cout << "a";}
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
    public:
        Base * basePtr;

        DerivedB()
          :basePtr(new DerivedA())
        {}

    protected:
        void doSomething() override {basePtr->doSomething();} // wont compile
};

int main(int , char *[])
{
   DerivedB b;
   b.go();
}
```

doSomething() in the DerivedB subclass will not compile, but I do not understand why this behavior exists! I am trying to access a virtual protected member function of my base class, which I would have thought would be allowed.

In the section on protected member access, it says

"A protected member of a class Base can only be accessed 1) by the members and friends of Base 2) by the members and friends (until C++17) of any class derived from Base, but only when operating on an object of a type that is derived from Base (including this)"

According to point 2, if I cast down to the subclass (DerivedA), this would be allowed but I would then be in conflict with the condition that I am accessing a protected member function of a different class (which is not a base class, and would also not compile). Worse, if I knew the sub class type of the derived object, I could still not access it even if I cast to its common base.

Why is this behavior enforced? I assume it is probably going to be a side effect of allowing multiple inheritance etc but I can't think of exactly what it would be. It's annoying because now I have to make a public interface for something which is and should only be used by base or derived classes, which goes against the point of inheritance and access modifiers.

link--http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access